# Extract elements from tuple to encode in python

Tags: list, tuples, python-unicode, unicode-string

I have a list of a list of tuples. With unicode problems.
I have be struggling to encode this into equivalent characters and I have been unsuccessful.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
import spaghetti as sgt
import codecs
f = codecs.open('output-data-pos', encoding='utf-8')
raw = f.read()
reviews = [raw.split()]
output_tagged = (sgt.pos_tag_sents(reviews))
```

Here is a sample of output_tagged produces.

```
 [[(u'cerramos', None), (u'igual', u'aq0cs0'), (u'arrancado', None), (u'estanter\xeda', None), (u'\xe9xito', u'ncms000'), (u'an\xe9cdotas', u'ncfp000')]]
```

My overall objective is to extract each value from the tuple and encode it in utf-8 for a final result such as

```
 cerramos   None
 igual  aq0cs0
 arrancado  None
 estantería None
 éxito  ncms000
 anécdotas  ncfp000
```

Some of the strategies that I have so far tried are from simple stratgies:

where i try to output the list and encode it directly

```
d = codecs.open('output-data-tagged', 'w', encoding='utf-8')
d.write(output_tagged)
```

or this approach

```
f = open('output-data-tagged', 'w')
for output in output_tagged:
    output.encode('utf-8')
    f.write(output)
f.close
```

where I first try to map the list and then encode it:

```
list_of_lists = map(list, output_tagged)
print list_of_lists
```

where I try functions to encode the data

```
def reprunicode(u):
     return reprunicode(u).decode('raw_unicode_escape')

print u'[%s]' % u', '.join([u'(%s,)' % reprunicode(ti[0]) for ti in output_tagged])
```

this one too:

```
def utf8data(list): 
     return [item.decode('utf8') for item in list]

print utf8data(output_tagged)
```

Considering my many trials, how can I extract the elements from the tuple in the list of list in order to arrive at my desired final encoding results?

Comment: Do you use Python 3?

Comment: @AhmadYoosofan no, python2.7

Comment: Sorry for my question because your print instruction in your last code shows the version, I don't remember the answer because of not working with Python 2 for years while I do had these problems. It is better to use Python 3 if you don't need special packages which run only on 2.